# I lost my wired connection but wifi works fine

Tags: internet, wired

I lost my wired connection but wifi works fine. Wired connection work but not have access to internet.
Ubuntu 16.04:

```
uname -v
#40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016
```

ifconfig -a

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:11:5b:2c:b8:a8  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:448 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6367 (6.3 KB)  TX bytes:39283 (39.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:92875 (92.8 KB)  TX bytes:92875 (92.8 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:10:7a:f9:83:ac  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ad8:a66c:5b3e:7794/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12534 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16778686 (16.7 MB)  TX bytes:1145205 (1.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is happening here. either your ethernet drivers are out of date/missing, which is resulting in it not connecting completely, or the cable or router ports that you are connecting to are faulty.

First, you should double check that is isn't the latter by hooking up another computer to the same cable and see what it does.

If that isn't the issue, you could try running this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

Comment: cable work on another computer

Comment: wifi work correct

Comment: If that fixed it, you should set my answer as the correct answer so others can figure this out too. Glad it's working now though!

Comment: Wifi working correct but not has wired connection

Comment: oh, sorry, i misread that. have you tried googling your Ethernet drivers, or checking what is currently installed?